# how bake three different materials belonging to an object into one single textured one

Tags: uv, baking

I have a texturing Question. I wish to make a textured bread sliced in 9 parts. I textured the whole bread with projection painting, and after that I sliced it in nine parts. In the holes created, I made a surface on every side of the slices which were textured creating a new UVMap and new material. Now I want to bake the three textures (the crust and the two sides) of every slice into one (the fourth), to export it to an external program, but every time, some parts remains white. However, the method works with the ends of the bread, where there is only a single section. I attach a blend file example with a slice and one end, sou you can see it. I use Blender 2.79, 64 bit in Windows, and I work with Blender Internal Renderer.  Thank you.
[image]

[blend file](http://www.aspekt.ro/fac/Bread.Slices.01.blend)

Answer (score 1):

After some correction I got the baked image.
[image]
[image]

Second Figure is original .blend. There were some errors.
The Map name on the right is painted with a caution color. In addition to it, there are blank names in Map of other textures. 
Blender is not specified what to use from multiple UV maps. 
And perhaps the active material of object _2B.004 is UVMat.2A.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! 2B.004 with 2B.003 and 2B.005  are the three sides of the unjoined parts of the slice put on the layer below, to have in blender their UVMaps and materials, from where to can bake the new texture. The joined and final mesh is 2B.001. Sorry for the confusing names. But there is another problem with your baked texture. The crust is not baked here, in it`s surface there is a texture from the section side.

Comment: @anegroo. OK. Bake after creating new 01_S.jpg texture of the material UVmat.1.

Comment: I uploaded a new .blend file.

Comment: Yes! I see that now, the baked texture is OK. But exactly what was changed? I can`t observ the difference... I tried to change everything in the original file, to match with your modified file, and I observed, that when I change the texture image of 2B.004 is also changing the 2B.005 texture, and vice versa. And when I try to bake again the final texture in your second file, again is wrong. I don`t understand! Thanks!

Comment: Finally I did it. I deleted the materials and texture of the individual objects and recreated them again. After that, I selected both Layers (with the individual objects and with the joined one), and now the new texture can baked correctly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @anegroo. In my file, Viewing Layer 11 is turned off. Could you set it visible for a training?

Comment: Yes, selecting both layers, the texture can baked correctly. Thank you for your help.